# how to echo a slash in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, jq

I have a string that is a json (that is stored in `MESSAGE`):

```
{"folder":"blah", "file":"halb"}
```

and I want to print in echo `blah/halb`.

I have tried:

- `echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.folder -r "/" echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.file -r` and it seems that it stays hanged
- `echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.folder -r "\/" echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.file -r` and it seems that it says `jq: \/: No such file or directory
  jq: echo: No such file or directory`

How do I print the slash?

Comment: You'll need something in between `jq` and `echo`, e.g. `&&`. And an `echo` before `"/"`.

Comment: :) I found it: `echo $(echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.cuReference -r)$'/'$(echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.landingName -r)` But how do I get just the file if the folder is not present, because this syntax is returning null/file if the folder field is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a single call to `jq`: use the `add` function for string concatenation:

```
jq -r '[.photo.folder, "/", .photo.file] | add' << END
{"photo": {"folder":"blah", "file":"halb"}}
END
```

```
blah/halb
```

---

Simpler: `jq -r '.photo.folder+ "/"+ .photo.file'`

Comment: You don't need the `add` filter, you can just use `+` to do the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
 echo $(echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.folder -r)$'/'$(echo $MESSAGE | jq .photo.file -r)
```

Comment: You don't really need ANSI quoting for a slash: it has no special powers so it don't need to be quoted at all. You are missing quotes around the important parts though: `echo "$(echo "$MESSAGE" | jq .photo.folder -r)/$(echo "$MESSAGE" | jq .photo.file -r)"`